# Finding source of Vim syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have installed Vim 8.0 on my Windows 7 and Windows 10 machines. When I edit a text file using restructured text (with a .txt extension) and use :set ft=rst, syntax highlighting starts up as expected.

Is there a Vim command to tell me which file is the source of these highlighting rules?

Answer (score 0):

Look into vim's [Filetype](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/filetype.html#:filetype) for this.

What I think you want to do is override the default. To do this you want to setup a custom `$HOME\vimfiles\filetype.vim`.

Here is an example where I want my `test.crazy` file to load like a `.html` file:

```
if exists("did_load_filetypes")
  finish
endif
augroup filetypedetect
  au! BufNewFile,BufRead *.crazy setf html
augroup END
```

However, this will only work if the filetype is not found. Example  [docs](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Filetype.vim).